# Image can not be set / display with space in name in Volley in Android

Tags: android, image, android-volley

I am getting image url from the server(i.e in API).

The image url is as follows ;

**"http://xyz.info/uploads/111968/Gruppenfoto kika Lehrlinge.jpg"**

which contains space in the name.

I have used following code using Volley image loader to display image ;

```
url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
holder.imgView.setImageUrl(url.toString(),MyVolley.getImageLoader());
```

But it does not set set/display image.

I have searched a lot about this , but could not get any solution.

Please help me.

Thanks.....

Comment: What you wrote is an invalid URL. Where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below code:

```
getImgUrl().replaceAll("[ ]", "%20");
```

Replace All Space with above code.

[GITHUB Sample/Lib SWIPEVOLLEY](https://github.com/DearDhruv/SwipeVolley)

Comment: Btw It is only works for Native OS.
I have tried in Samsung devices and does not work.
Nexus and Motorola and devices which has almost clean OS are giving the correct output.

Comment: better to find the best solution for all OS.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `URLEncoder.encode()` instead of `string.replace()`

***EDIT***

Your problem might be that when you first ran your code, you did not URL encode the spaces, the image could naturally not be found and this fact was saved in the ImageLoader cache. You might want to clear the cache for this particular URL and try again
`AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);`
or even better disable the cache while testing whith `setShouldCache(false);`

Furthermore, in order to find out the kind of error that prevents you from showing the proper image, you could replace the NetworkImageView with a regular ImageView and use this code

```
// If you are using normal ImageView
imageLoader.get(url, new ImageListener() {

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Image Load Error: " + error.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
        // load image into imageview
        imageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
    }
}
```

});
```

Comment: we have used it but not been useful

Comment: Are you using a Volley NetworkImageView in the xml layout? Have you properly initialized the ImageLoader with a RequestQueue and an ImageCache?

Comment: Have you tried loading a static resource to your ImageView? It might be a layout problem. Could you post the layout and ImageLoader code?

Comment: I think it is not the layout problem because if i set static local image or server url without space in name, it works fine.